# How to take a Packard Bell Maestro LCD Monitor apart?

Tags: display, lcd

Does anybody know how to take a Packard Bell Maestro LCD Monitor apart? I need to separate the layers of the screen in order to remove a fly which is stuck inside it. There are no screws on the back which makes me even wonder if it is even possible to open it up. Any help would be much appreciated.

-Alex

Comment: Do you mean the whole monitor or the panel? I've opened up a monitor before - the ones i opened up used clips AND screws. Update your question with photos, and we'd be better able to help. The pictures i've seen does make it look like there's no obvious screws - check under the label. It might also be held together by clips which means you need to gently seperate it with a spudger or other suitable pry tool - are there any small notches between the bezel and the rest of the case?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I just look another quick look and after fiddling with the frame I have found that it might be able to be pry'd open as there was some movement. I do not have a spudger, what tool would you recommend to do this?

Comment: I used a common flathead screwdriver. It *will* damage the frame however, especially the first time. If i did it again, i'd spend the 10 or so dollars on a set of them - Its probably worth it.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks. I will try that tomorrow with a set of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information i have, I'd guess your monitor is held together by clips between the bezel and back. Taking apart your monitor WILL void your warranty - and its not easy to do cleanly without practice. With the BenQ monitors i've taken apart in the past, there was an obvious slot to take it apart in the middle bottom of the frame.Make sure that there's no screws, especially under labels - if there are any undo them.

When i did it, i used a small flathead screwdriver, and a set of sharpened dowels (acting as wedges to keep the pryed apart parts apart). Start at one point, pry, and wedge, and work your way around the edge of the area between the bezel and back of the case. If it won't come apart, check for non obvious screws. You may prefer to use a set of spudgers (ifixit and others have them) - they are pretty cheap and probably worth it if you wanted to avoid cosmetic damage.

Comment: Oh, while the panels i worked with had CCFL backlight, be VERY careful with any small wires that are in your way. I'm assuming cracking it open should be enough, but should you need to remove the lcd panel for any reason, you will also need a crosshead eyeglass screwdriver